# CC.Net cannot get code from SVN: Source Control Failure (GetModifications)

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I don't know why setting up CC.Net can never be easy... sigh. All I'm trying to do is get CC.Net to download the code from SVN and that's it. Won't work.

Here is my config (paths changed to protect the innocent):

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <executable>C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
  <trunkUrl>svn://MyCompany/MyProject/trunk</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>C:\Projects\MyProject\trunk</workingDirectory>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
</sourcecontrol>
```

When I try and force the build in CC.Net to see if it can download the code, I get these errors in the command window:

1) **"C:\Projects\MyProject\trunk is not a svn working folder"**

I don't understand that one. What am I supposed to do about that?

Then CC.Net hangs on the "CheckingModifications" part forever before finally spitting this at me:

2) **"Source control failure (GetModifications): Source control operation failed: svn: Connection closed unexpectedly."**

I'm baffled. No clue where to start on this one. Google has been unhelpful.

Comment: Fixed this. Was a problem with two things: 1) trunkUrl (ours needed to be http:// instead of svn://) and 2) username and password.

Comment: Yeah.  Mine was the <password> missing.  The error message is not very intuitive.  Upvote for helping me resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was a problem with two things: 1) trunkUrl (ours needed to be http:// instead of svn://) and 2) username and password

Answer (score 1):

First, after years of beating myself silly with CCNET, I found out that [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is awesome and free for small-scale use. Takes standing up CI on a given project from a "half day of hair pulling and cursing followed by 2 days of heavy drinking" to "it'll be up when you get back from lunch" style experience.

As for the problem at hand, I'd try running the SVN command line in the context of the CCNET process to see what is going on--issue sounds environmental in some way, and having the SVN output would help.

Comment: I had no idea TeamCity had a free version Wyatt. Thanks for pointing that out. I may have to give that a try. I've done three different CC.Net setups in the last few years and every single one of them was a multi-day hair pulling pain. I'd rather have a root canal.

Answer (score 1):

CCNET first checks for the existence of the working directory. If the directory exists it check for the existence of **.svn or _svn** files.
If the directory already exists do a `svn co` and see if CCNET works after that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <sourcecontrol type="multi">
      <sourceControls autoGetSource="true">
        <svn>
          <trunkUrl>svn://1.1.1.1:3690/Working_Projects/YourProject/</trunkUrl>
          <username>adminX</username>
          <password>1234</password>          <workingDirectory>C:\CruiseControl\ProjectFolders\WorkingFolder</workingDirectory>
        </svn>
       </sourceControls>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but hopefully this will help someone.

The problem we had was CCNET was unable to access an external hard drive, because a user was removed from our build machine. Ensuring CCNET had access to all directories involved in our build process fixed this issue.